# Concerns about memory leaks in react's event listeners

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks

Will react take care of event listeners and remove them on state change?
Look at the code below, I used onClick for an HtmlElement. The element itself can be removed when the state changed. Will react clean the event listener or do I have to clean every listener by myself every time a user is removed?

```
class Users extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: this.props.data };
  }
  remove = (i) => {
    this.state.data.splice(i,1);
    this.setState({data: this.state.data});
  };
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map((user, i) => {
          return <div key={i}>
            <span>{user.name}</span>
            <input type='button' value='remove' onClick={(e) => this.remove(i)} />
          </div>
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about cleaning it. React will take care of that for you. React uses a virtual DOM, so that's the key difference there.

You could optimize your code though, by removing the arrow function from your `onClick` and binding an existing function instead.

More info and examples here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#bind-in-constructor-es2015

And here is some explanation of why arrow function may not be the best option:

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render